# Scholarship rejection | Should I tell Supervisor

Tags: graduate-admissions

So I applied to an MASc program in Canada where basically the supervisor approves students to admit. I applied for a separate departmental scholarship and got rejected. Is it a good idea to tell the supervisor about this? 
Supervisor said he hasn't sent out the final decisions to the graduate studies department and he'll decide in a month. Also, the scholarship I applied for is separate from the funding that he provides.
My point is he did not specifically ask for me to apply here. I initiated it and he told me I could try. Would complete transparency in this case help me or kill the chances I have?

Comment: Unless there are IP to protect and/or an industrial partner funding any of the scholarships, I don't think supervisors would mind (at least experienced ones). It all comes down to where the money comes from. Usually there is a billing account from which scholarships are funded. Getting funded from another source actually works in his/her favour by freeing up funds for one more student. Not sure if internal politics would play a role here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I agree. The scholarship was for my tuition only and he did not recommend it in the first place. It was just a top-up. Anyways, let's hope I get accepted :)

Comment: I don't think it would be wrong of you to not mention this until you're accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a Canadian academic, who also sits on a graduate committee. These decisions are separate, as you note, and I would not feel obligated to mention this to your supervisor. He might or might not know the outcome of these scholarships, depending on how engaged he is with the program's funding picture.

My advice in this circumstance would be to wait for the admissions decision.